# Interpretation of binomial parameters in zeroinfl in R

Tags: r, zero-inflation

In the help page of `zeroinfl`, it says "**a binary model is used that captures the probability of zero inflation**." But it seems it is modeling the opposite of that (see the code below). Am I interpreting the verbal description wrong? Because arguably, if p is modelled, 1-p is automatically modelled, and vice versa.

```
n <- 10000
y <- rpois(n,3)
p <- 0.3        # probability of zero inflation
zi <- rbinom(n,size=1,prob=p)==0
y <- y*zi       # zero inflated poisson

library(pscl)
(model <- zeroinfl(y~1|1,dist="poisson"))
exp(coef(model)[2])/(1-exp(coef(model)[2])) # this seems 1-p instead of p
```

Answer (score 1):

The computation of the probability was wrong. It should be:

```
exp(coef(model)[2])/(1+exp(coef(model)[2]))
```